# Git Bash mkdir command crashed and created us.stackdump file

Tags: git

I just installed Git-1.8.4-preview20130916 to my win7 64bit machine. I opened Git Bash window and tried to create my first repos folder - I run mkdir repos. However, it just crashed and created a us.stackdump  file in the \user\Administrator folder. The content is as follows:

```
MSYS-1.0.12 Build:2012-07-05 14:56
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=68086014
eax=68570000 ebx=00005B34 ecx=000016CD edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=68570000
ebp=0028FE48 esp=0028FE3C program=us
cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0028FE48  68086014  (68570000, 00000000, 00005B34, 00000004)
0028FE98  68001CB0  (00482C50, 00000001, 0028FEE8, 680044EA)
0028FEE8  680045C7  (7097703F, 7097703F, 0028FF28, 00407108)
0028FF08  68004C5F  (0040152C, 00000000, 0040003E, 007009F0)
0028FF28  68004C98  (00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
0028FF58  00407018  (0040152C, 004843B0, 0000066C, 0000017D)
0028FF88  0040103D  (7EFDE000, 0028FFD4, 77BB9F72, 7EFDE000)
0028FF94  774F336A  (7EFDE000, 77646570, 00000000, 00000000)
0028FFD4  77BB9F72  (00401000, 7EFDE000, 00000000, 00000000)
0028FFEC  77BB9F45  (00401000, 7EFDE000, 00000000, 78746341)
End of stack trace
```

It seems to me it's an access-denied problem. So I exit my firewall program and also I run Git Bash program as administrator. But It still didn't work.

I open command line window and run mkdir.exe from C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin folder to create repos fold in user\administrator\ folder and it was created.

It's my first time to use Git, could anyone give me some help?

Thanks

Comment: From your git bash window, type "which mkdir" without quotes and tell us what it says.

Comment: I ran the command and it returned -  /bin/mkdir

Answer (score 0):

You can see this [issue 25](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/25), linked to a 32-bys msys-1.0.dll (also in [issue 8](https://github.com/msysgit/git/issues/8)).

It is suggested to ["rebase" msys-1.0.dll](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/E_10hr9ASMY)... but don't forget you don't have to use a git bash for those command.
A simple DOS session is enough, provided `<path\to\PortableGit-1.8.4-preview20130916\bin>` is in your `%PATH%`.

Comment: A lot of other commands don't work. So I decide to use UI client for git like sourcetree. It's working fine, but it still generate us.stackdump file.

Comment: @Tianze Your SourceTree is based on your current msysgit installation. Open a DOS windows, do as instructed the `<path\to\PortableGit-1.8.4-preview20130916\bin\rebase.exe -b 0x30000000 /path/to/msys-1.0.dll`, and launch *from that same DOS windows* your SourceTree.